# How to escape special characters in Hana DB Password using SQL query?

Tags: hana

I am trying to update/reset User password in HANA Database using SQL query(JDBC) like below, but getting sql syntax error.

Query:

**ALTER USER TEST_USER PASSWORD Marc@4321**

Error:

**SAP DBTech JDBC: [257] (at 35): sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "@": line 1 col 35 (at pos 35)**

How to escape special characters in Hana DB SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy to do by enclosing the new password in double-quotation marks:

```
ALTER USER TEST_USER PASSWORD "Marc@4321"
```

Comment: Thanks @Lars Br. your answer worked. It is working without double-quotation marks only if password doesn't contain any special characters.